# Jumper wire in 1980's synths

Tags: components

I am trying to find this exact cable - does anyone know what this is called?
1980's Roland [TB 303](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roland_TB-303) Bass Synthesizer.

These are jumpers between traces. I want to know where to get this cable and why it would be used all over the synthesizer. Is being wound like this more resistant to EM interference and prevents emitting EM ?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FoXjB.jpg]

Comment: Please edit your question to explain what a TB303 is, where the links are used and why you think there is anything special about those conductors that couldn't be replaced with copper wire links.

Comment: It just looks like tinned stranded wire.

Comment: I can't believe anyone doesn't know what a TB303 is. It's like asking for clarification regarding a Fender Strat or a Stradivarius.

Comment: It looks like a two layer board with no plated through holes, so the jumpers may have some form of insulation on them?

Comment: It's called "wire".

Comment: @IanBland TR-808, I know. TB-303, never heard of before today :)

Comment: @hobbs Looks like something you could [replace with a small perl script](https://www.reddit.com/r/talesfromtechsupport/comments/27b0sl/begone_or_i_shall_replace_you_with_a_perl_script/)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like 24 or 22-AWG, 7-strand copper wire, "tinned" or solder-coated.

"Jumper" wires can be any type of wire - insulated, non-insulated, stranded, solid, etc. Most often, solid wire is used, and it is tin-plated to reduce corrosion.

In Metric units 23AWG would be around 0.5mm. Simply obtain some of this, commonly refered to as "hookup wire", strip off any insulation, give it a slight twist, and [tin it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8jUaf394WIk) with a soldering iron to have exactly what is shown here.

Comment: Yes this is what I was wondering, it looks stranded but it's very hard and definitely coated in something, I have not cut one so I can't see what the cross section is.

Comment: I would imagine if it is coated with anything, it could be polyurethane. They certainly went though a lot of trouble for a simple jumper wire. :)

Comment: I am convinced it was produced like this into reels because they made 10,000 Roland TB-303's. They were made by hand in Japan. Could I take a length of stranded wire and dip 2 m of it into molten solder in a crucible if the wire was pre-coated in flux?

Comment: Probably, but as the wire is removed it has to remain still for a few seconds so it solidifies smoothly. If it is bumped, the solder will take on a dull finish.